# How to calculate the average temperature in 5 minute intervals?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a practice problem, and need some help calculating the average temperature for 5 minute intervals. Here are the instructions from the problem:

The first column in the .txt file is time in minutes. The second column in the .txt file is temperature in degrees Fahrenheit.

- Calculate the average temperature in 5 minute intervals by slicing the array(can also be done using a loop).
- Plot the data from the .txt file and the averages on the same plot with time on the x-axis and temperature on the y-axis.
- Plot data1 in red.
- Plot the 5 minute averages of data1 in blue (plot them in the middle of the average, aka for the average of 1 to 5 min plot it at 3 min).

I'm mainly confused on calculating the average temperature in a 5 minute interval and then on how to graph those averages for the time average of the interval. I'll also include the code that I have below, but it is missing those two parts of the problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt("sample1.txt")    
middle_of_interval = np.average()

plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], "r") 
plt.title("Temperature vs. Time")  
plt.xlabel("Time (minutes)")        
plt.ylabel("Temperature (F)")       
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 30, 1))     
plt.yticks(np.arange(23, 27, 0.5))
```

Comment: Please include a sample of your data in a code block. Makes it a lot easier for us to understand your question and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to avoid looping over arrays; better to stick to slicing and other tricks.

You can get a moving average over 5 elements of an array `arr` like so:

```
avg = (arr[:-4] + arr[1:-3] + arr[2:-2] + arr[3:-1] + arr[4:]) / 5
```

You could also convolve a small boxcar with the time series, like so:

```
boxcar = np.ones(5) / 5
avg = np.convolve(arr, boxcar, mode='valid')
```

Do the same thing to the time series to get the average time of each measurement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prompt the user to enter the temperature in Fahrenheit .
2. Convert the temperature celsius to by using the following formula.

   **F=c×9/5+32**
3. Print the output.